# Formatting a LaTeX list as an HTML table

Tags: tables, lists, tex4ht

Is it possible to add some configuration somewhere in order to have LaTeX list, such as:

```
\begin{customlist}
 \item[keyword1] Description.
 \item[keyword2] Another description.
 \item[keyword3] Yet another.
\end{customlist}
```

formated as an HTML table by tex4ht, something like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>keyword1</td><td>Description.</td></tr>
<tr><td>keyword2</td><td>Another description.</td></tr>
<tr><td>keyword3</td><td>Yet another.</td></tr>
</table>
```

?

Before you tell me that if I want a table I should use `tabular`, I'll say that I'm trying to adapt an old LaTeX document by modifying the `.sty` files, introducing as few changes as possible in the `.tex`. The `customlist` environment is defined as a list, introducing some kind of header, so the LaTeX output already looks a bit like a table.

My main problem with `tex4t` is that the descriptions are not the argument to any command, so I don't know how to introduce the `</td></tr>`part at the end of each row. The rest would probably be something along the lines of:

```
\ConfigureList{customlist}{\Tg<table>}{\Tg</table>}{\Tg<tr>\Tg<td>}{\Tg</td><td>}
```

But of course, that does not create a valid table (at least not in XHTML, which is what I'd prefer).

Something that formats the list as a tabular in LaTeX would be welcome too.

Comment: Note the `</td></tr>` are optional in HTML, it is valid, and parses the same way, without them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right, of course... I guess I meant XHMTML, I've edited the question :)

Comment: what about something like (untested): `\ConfigureList{customlist}
{\Tg<table>\def\trtdend{}}
{\Tg</table>}
{\trtdend\HCode{<tr><td>}\def\trtdend{\HCode{</td></tr>}}}
{\Tg</td><td>}`

Comment: @michal.h21 Interesting... I'd need to add `\trtdend` before the `</table>` too, but it seems to do the work.

Comment: ok, I will add it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some helper macro:

```
\ConfigureList{customlist}
{\Tg<table>\def\trtdend{}}
{\trtdend\Tg</table>}
{\trtdend\HCode{<tr><td>}\def\trtdend{\HCode{</td></tr>}}}
{\Tg</td><td>}
```

Macro `\trtdend` is inserted in at every item. It is set empty at begining of the environment and in first item it is set to `\HCode{</td></tr>}` so these tags are correctly closed at every next item or at the end of the environment